# phpstorm: where's the class browser?

Tags: php, phpstorm

New to phpstorm, I can't find the class browser (OSX).

Where is it?

Regards,
//t

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In left bottom corner button "Structure"

Comment: aaahhh.. (major relief). Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to dock stuff above and below each other in the sidebars? Or is it a single item per sidebar?

Comment: @DavidYell It is possible. Move at least two panels to one side and mark one of them as `Split mode` (option available in panel configuration, right top corner of the panel). Checked in PhpStorm 2016.2 EAP